# How to inherit UserDict and metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```py
from collections import UserDict

class Meta(type):
    pass

class A(UserDict, metaclass=Meta):
    pass

a = A()
```

But it ran wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    class A(UserDict, metaclass=Meta):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I'm very confused about this error (because I think it will work), can anyone explain it, and what's the correct way to inherit UserDict and metaclass

Comment: Is there a reason you need `UserDict` instead of just `dict`?

Comment: The metaclass of `UserDict` is `type(UserDict)` = `<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>`, and your `Meta` metaclass is not a subclass of it.

Comment: @0x5453 Because I heard that there are some problems in using `dict` for inheritance

Comment: @ThierryLathuille So change the `type` to `abc.ABCMeta` Is that a good idea? Or is there any other way

Comment: what does >> a.__class__ is type(obj) returns ?

Comment: Once upon a time you *couldn't* inherit from `dict`, which is why `UserDict` was defined. But now you *can* inherit from `dict`, so you should do that unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: @pippo1980 `a` is never created and `obj` doesn't exist. What are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry missed that ;-) type is the metaclass of all classes try to see if changing type with something else  my statement above works